# Image not displaying in browser

Tags: html

My image is not displaying in the browser and yet I seem to specify the correct url. What might be the problem? Here is the image tag:
`<img src="C:/wamp/www/simple/images/greener.png" alt="Grass" width="400" height="400" />`
It only displays the alternative text "Grass". Where could I be wrong? Help please.

Comment: That's a link to a file. It should instead point to a `http://localhost...` or use the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've used `http://localhost` like this `<img src="http://localhost/simple/images/greener.png" alt="Grass" width="400" height="400" />` and image now displays.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and mark my answer as correct (by checking the outline checkmark next to it). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a link to a file. It should instead point to a `http://localhost...` or use the `file:///` protocol.

```
http://localhost/simple/images/greener.png
```

(Note, I'm guessing `C:/wamp/www/` is your webroot.)

Or:

```
file:///C:/wamp/www/simple/images/greener.png
```

Note, both of these only work if you are accessing a local file using a local server or local file using a local file. If you want others to get to it, you need to use a valid domain name available on your network or the internet at large.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using apache webserver as part of a wamp stack. For security reasons most browsers don't allow http-pages to contain images with file-URLs so they just ignore them.

You should use a http-URL in your img-tag, not a file-URL.

Comment: Fine info I appreciate. Thank you